# mysql select with join very slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B. A has about 29 million rows and B is a temporary table with about 1000 rows.

The query is as below -

```
select DISTINCT Table_A.column_a from Table_B join Table_A on Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_a;
```

I have a composite index key2 on (ID_a, column_a)

The query takes about 20 secs to run.

The explain is as below -

```
------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys                           | key                       | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_B           | ALL  | NULL                                    | NULL                      | NULL    | NULL                                  | 1507 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_A           | ref  | key1 ,key2                              | key2                      | 3       | DB_name.Table_B.ID_b                  |  963 | Using index     |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-----------------+
```

How can I optimize this query?

Thanks

```
desc Table_A 
| id       | bigint(8) unsigned    | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| column_a | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO | MUL |      |                | 
| column_1 | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO | MUL |      |                |
| id_a     | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO | MUL |      | 
| column_2 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO | MUL | NULL |                | 
| column_3 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO |     | NULL |                | 
| column_4 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO | MUL | NULL |                | 
| column_5 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO |     | NULL |                |
```

Comment: Have the tables index over the IDs?

Comment: Have you got an index on Table_B.ID_b?

Comment: pls post your table structure,tkx

Comment: desc Table_A

| id   | bigint(8) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| column_a    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL |  |                |
| column_1  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL ||        |
| id_a  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | |
| column_2 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| column_3   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| column_4 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| column_5 | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                ||
  |

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on the temporary table B, column ID_b, you should'nt get anymore the 'Using temporary in the "Extra" column after that and it should be better. Use a [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) statement.

Comment: Added the index but still see using temporary

Comment: @kkszysiu - Added the index but still see using temporary

Comment: @regilero - - Added the index but still see using temporary

Comment: @Se D ok, but now you should'nt get NULL in the Key column, stating that the available index is used. And you could try a key on Id_a different than key_2 (without the composite)

Comment: @regilero - I don't get NULL in the key column any more. So are you saying do not use the composite key and only use the key on Id_a?

Comment: @se D, if you do not get the NULL in the key column that mean the key is used, so that's fine. You should already get some performance gain

Comment: @regilero - Again no luck. Infact it takes longer. The explain looks like below - ---+------+------------------------------+| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref    | rows |Extra                        |+----+------------------------------+|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_B | index | ID_index      | ID_index      | 3       | NULL                                  | 1507 | Using index; Using temporary ||  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_A         | ref   | key_on_Id_a | key_on_Id_a | 3       | DB_name.Table_B.ID_b | 1933 |                              |

Comment: @regilero - The time increased from 20 secs to 2 mins 46 secs

Answer (score 0):

try create an index on tableA with the following column (column_a)

Comment: I added an index an d the explain still looks the same

Answer (score 0):

Add proper indexes on a colums. Explain should help there and it should speed up your query a lot.

Comment: Extra                        |+----+------+------------------------------+|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_B | index | ID_index                                | ID_index                  | 3       | NULL                                  | 1507 | Using index; Using temporary ||  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_A         | ref   | key1,key2 | key2 | 3       | DB_name.Table_B.ID_b |  240 | Using index

Comment: @kkszysiuExtra |+----+------+------------------------------+| 1 | SIMPLE | Table_B | index | ID_index | ID_index | 3 | NULL | 1507 | Using index; Using temporary || 1 | SIMPLE | Table_A | ref | key1,key2 | key2 | 3 | DB_name.Table_B.ID_b | 240 | Using index –

Answer (score 0):

do not change any index

EDIT
i miss the index's order, change the key2 to (column_a, id_a)

Try:

```
select DISTINCT Table_A.column_a 
from Table_A straight_join 
Table_B on Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_a;
```

pls show the explain result ,tkx

Comment: @Neo - Does not help.--+------------------------------+ | 1 | SIMPLE | Table_A | index | key1,key2 | key2 | 6 | NULL | 29252089 | Using index; Using temporary | | 1 | SIMPLE | Table_B | ref | ID_index | ID_index | 3 | DN_name.Table_A.ID_a | 1 | Using index; Distinct

Comment: how about select Table_A.column_a 
from Table_A straight_join 
Table_B on Table_B.ID_b = Table_A.ID_a group by Table_A.column_a

Comment: modify the Table_A index key2 to  key2(column_a, id_a)

Comment: @Neo - Let me try the key2 change. I have tried Group by and that did not help

Comment: @Neo - Why do you think the change in key2 will help?

Comment: my query use straight_join and first execute is Table_A, mysql will use lose index scan for group by

Comment: @Neo - No luck! Now the explain looks as following - | id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key                       | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_A        | index | key1 | key2 | 6       | NULL | 29421999 | Using index; Using temporary   |  1 | SIMPLE      | Table_B | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL | 1507 | Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer

Comment: hava you try change the distinct to group by?